# HTML text area change position of placeholder

Tags: html, input, textarea, placeholder

I want my text input area to be bigger but have the placeholder text in the top left corner. How do I accomplish this?

[JSFiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nightcoregirl/crkej7kp/)

```
<form name="myForm" class="infocontent">
   <input data-role="none" type="email" class="inputEmail required" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL"/> </br></br>
   <input data-role="none" type="text" class="inputMessage messageHeight required" name="message"  placeholder="MESSAGE" style="width:400px; height:100px;"/> </br> </br>

   <div id="load"></div>
   <input data-role="none" type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a [textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) for your message? Then the placeholder will be in the corner, too.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with pseudo elements and css, but you have to do one for each browser:

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */

    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    position:0 0;
    height: 100px;
    width:400px;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */

    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    position:0 0;
    height: 100px;
    width:400px;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */

    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    position:0 0;
    height: 100px;
    width:400px;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */

    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    position:0 0;
    height: 100px;
    width:400px;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" class="infocontent">
        <input data-role="none" type="email" class="inputEmail required" name="email" placeholder="EMAIL"/> </br></br>
          <input data-role="none" type="text" class="inputMessage messageHeight required" name="message"  placeholder="MESSAGE" style="width:400px; height:100px;"/> </br> </br>

           <div id="load"></div>
           <input data-role="none" type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="submit"/>
          </form>
```

The above example will allow you to modify the placeholder code however you like with CSS.

Comment: The placeholder just isnt in the topleft corner in Firefox 55.

Comment: @Tobias is the placeholder visible at all? ie, is it present, just not in the corner?

Comment: The placeholder ist visible. But it is vertically centered.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this problem now and I tried the solution @BlackHatSamurai gave but didn't work.

I'm putting it here in case someone is dumb as me and still finding the answer for this.

I assume what you are trying to do here is making a textarea, I tried using`<input type="textarea" placeholder="Message">` but the placeholder is always in the middle. No matter how you style it, you can just style the placeholder with limited amount of properties see this link for more info  [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/)

And I found as I am writing this post that there is no such thing as `<input type="textarea"` , but the browser is still rendering it to the DOM as `<input type="text">`. So I got confused and spend hours debugging the wrong element. You can see this behavior in the snippet below

I solved this by just replacing the `<input type="textarea" placeholder="Message">` with `<textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>`.
placeholder is set in top left corner of the element by default.

```css
input[type="textarea"],
textarea {
display:block;
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
}
```

```html
Input:<input type="textarea" placeholder="Message">
Textarea:<textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea>
```